# Choosing a value from 2 lines

Tags: ssrs-2008

I am trying to create a table in SQL Server Report Builder that shows the number of tickets opened and closed in a month and I came up with this query that partially does what I want:

SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(incident_id) AS TicketsOpened, Datepart(Year, open_time) AS InYear, Datepart(MONTH, open_time) AS YrMonth, DateName(MONTH, open_time) AS MnName, 'Open' as Tickets

FROM         HROHelpDeskSD

WHERE     (Datepart(Year, open_time) = (YEAR(GETDATE())))

GROUP BY Datepart(Year, open_time), Datepart(MONTH, open_time), DateName(MONTH, open_time)

UNION

SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(incident_id) AS TicketsClosed, Datepart(Year, close_time) AS CloseYear, Datepart(MONTH, close_time) AS YrMonth, DateName(MONTH, close_time) AS MnName, 'Closed' as Tickets

FROM         HROHelpDeskSD

WHERE     (Datepart(Year, close_time) = (YEAR(GETDATE())))

GROUP BY Datepart(Year, close_time), Datepart(MONTH, close_time), DateName(MONTH, close_time)

order by YrMonth

which produces:

TicketsOpened InYear   YrMonth              MnName             Tickets

1879                       2017         1                             January               Open

1855                       2017         1                             January               Closed .

But then I got stumped trying to get the number that need to put in the field on the table.  If the Tickets is Open then I need to put the corresponding number in the Tickets Opened field and the same for Closed into the Tickets Closed field.  Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Donald

Comment: Can you show me what the output should look like. Do you want something like

`Year MonthNumber MonthName Opened Closed`
`2107     1                       January   1879      1855`

Comment: If the user is requesting Open tickets for January I need to return 1879 or 1855 if the request is for Closed tickets.

Comment: So Open/Closed is a parameter on the report? I had assumed you wanted to see both values on the report.
Can you post the exact output you expect to see and I'm sure it'll be simple once I understand exactly what you need.

Comment: I have 2 tables and graphs that I would like to try and combine them but to do that I need one query that will provide the numbers open and the numbers closed and I don't just want to a difference between them because I looking for how many are opened in a given month and how are closed in a given month.  Unfortunately, the system will not allow me to paste a screen shot in here.